# EF code-first 1:* 1:0..1 relationship between the same models

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two models

```
public class A{
    public AID { get; set; }

    public int? MainBID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MainBID")]
    public B MainB { get; set; }
}
public class B{
    public int BID { get; set; }

    public int? AID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AID")]
    public virtual A Owner { get; set;}
}
```

The relationship I want to model is A has many B. A may also have a specially designated B (main B).

However the way I have it set up it has a hard time identifying the principal and using fluent:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<A>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.MainB)
    .WithOptionalDependent();
```

It gives me Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'A_MainB_Source' in relationship 'A_MainB'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

I think my trouble is trying to describe to EF that these are two separate relationships and not the same relationship described front-and-back. Can anyone guide me in this?

EDIT: Adds an real life example

I have need to model a series of teaching courses (each is called a "Module"). All "Modules" represent a webpage conveying the information for that particular course. Each Module can have many "Resource"s (downloadable binary files).

Some modules can have a Resource that represents the same information as the webpage. As in some modules can have a Resource that can be printed out and consumed instead of sitting in front of your machine reading through the webpage. A PDF version of the webpage.

So in the above each module has many resources. But each module can optionally have a "special" resource that needs to be called out separately as well as wherever other resources are used.

I considered just having a flag on Resource to indicate that a resource is special in some way but that will allow for 0..* which is not what I want. I thought this might be cleaner. But I have so far not been able to get this to work with EF.

Comment: can you give a real life example of what you are trying to do? (I cannot understand the kind of relations, A->Many B (your model does not look like that!)

Comment: @LucianBumb see the edit I added.

Answer (score 0):

this is a working example:

```
public class Module
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
       public int? SpecialResourceId { get; set; }
       public Resource SpecialResource { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ModuleId { get; set; }
        public Module Module { get; set; }
        public virtual Module IsSpecialForModule { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Resource> Resources { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           modelBuilder.Entity<Module>()
                .HasMany(x=>x.Resources)
                .WithOptional(x=>x.Module)
                .HasForeignKey(x=>x.ModuleId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Resource>()
                .HasOptional(x=>x.IsSpecialForModule)
                .WithOptionalDependent(x=>x.SpecialResource)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
```

if your special resource, can be special for many modules then your model is changing like this:

```
 public class Resource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ModuleId { get; set; }
        public Module Module { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Module> IsSpecialForModules { get; set; }
    }
```

and the config. will be :

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Resources>()
                .HasMany(x=>x.IsSpecialForModules )
                .WithOptional(x=>x.SpecialResource )
                .HasForeignKey(x=>x.SpecialResourceId )
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: if a resource can be special for many modules, then you need to have also one to many for resource->modules

Comment: This solution is really interesting in a number of ways. Is the "IsSpecialForModule" navigation property absolutely necessary? In my example the special resource will always be special to that specific module.

Comment: you get compilation error if you delete the navigation property, without this prop you cannot configure the relation. But like I said one resource, may be special for many modules, so thing how you configure that relation. If you go from start with many modules may have the same special res. you have nothing to lose.